# How to report a WildFly 8 bug

Tags: websocket, wildfly

I found a bug in the websocket implementation of WildFly 8.0.0: the CloseReason received by the onClose methods of the enpoints is always null. GlassFish 4.0 does not have the issue.

What is the proper way to check if the bug is not already known, then report it?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default issue tracker for WildFly is https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY.

If you can isolate your issue on Undertow (the web server component), then https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW might be a better place to check or to report the issue.